# Linq to SQL without using InheritanceMapping on a column

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new to Linq to SQL. I have 5 fields that all exist in 20 tables. I created a base class with the 5 fields. Then I then created 20 classes that inherit from this base class. Linq could not map to them. After some searching, I see I am supposed to hand this by adding an `InheritanceMapping` and a `Column` attribute above the properties. But this does not work for me.

Here is an example of what seems to be expected:

```
[InheritanceMapping(Type = typeof(Motorcycle), IsDefault = true, Code = 1)]
[Table]
public class Vehicle
{
    [Column]
    public string Make { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [Column(IsDiscriminator = true, Name="VehicleTypeId")]
    public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
}

public class Motorcycle : Vehicle
{
    // implementation here
}
```

This does not work for me, because there is no field for `VehicleTypeId` in the database. All I am really doing is applying 5 fields across classes which are otherwise unrelated. Here's what I am actually trying to do:

```
public enum BaseTypes {
    AnyClassAtAll = 1,
    SomeOtherClass = 2
}

public abstract class BaseClass {
    [Column(Name = "Record_Inserted", DbType = "datetime", CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime RecordInserted { get; set; }

    // This column does not exist in the database and
    // is only added for inheritance for Linq
    [Column(IsDiscriminator = true)]
    public BaseTypes BaseType;
}

[InheritanceMapping(Type = typeof(AnyClassAtAll), Code = BaseTypes.AnyClassAtAll)]
public class AnyClassAtAll : BaseClass {
    [Column(Name = "FOO", DbType = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public AnyClassAtAll() {
        BaseType = BaseTypes.AnyClassAtAll;
    }
}
```

Linq fails because it cannot map anything to the `BaseType` field.

Comment: I tried to make a very small example to highlight the approach I took. I pasted in the InheritanceMapping on the new class rather than at the base class where it should be. The code I have is correct I believe. The reason it fails for me is due to the fact that BaseType is not a real column name which is what I am asking about in my OP.

Comment: Why not just define an interface for these 5 common fields, declare the class partials as implementing that interface, and then when you want to refer to those classes in terms of the 5 common fields, pass them by interface. Since the classes are not related, it doesn't make sense to make some kind of mapping hack :)

Comment: I like the thought. And you are correct that the classes are unrelated other than sharing 5 common fields, so an interface defining a 'contract' of how the classes should look is technically a better way to go. But then I still need all the same properties defined in all classes. Also, attributes are not part of that contract so the Linq [Column()] attribute is not enforced allowing possible mistakes there. I have currently updated all my classes to have the fields and no longer inherit, but I will possibly add the interface as well to enforce the properties are all defined the same.

Comment: @StephenByrne - Based on the research I've done, I do not believe what  I want is possible. Therefore the best way to enforce that the fields are all there is an interface. It doesn't solve the mapping, but it ensures that class properties are all defined correctly. Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my previous comment, you could define an `interface` that specifies the shared columns:

```
public interface IVehicleBaseProperties
{
    DateTime RecordInserted{get;set;}
    string Make{get;set;}
    string Model {get;set;}
    VehicleType VehicleType{get;set;}
    //etc.

}
```

and then create partial class files (remember L2S creates the mapped classes as partial so you can extend them)

```
public partial class MotorCycle:IVehicleBaseProperties
{
}
```

*Note that you shouldn't need to do anything more than this* because as long as `RecordInserted`,`Make`,`Model`, etc, are present in the *auto-generated* `partial`, then the interface is satisfied.

Anyway you can now pass around instances of Bikes, Cars, Batmobiles, etc, as `IVehicleBaseProperties` since any "common" function can only be operating on those common properties because the classes are not in fact related.

Hope that helps.